# c# Update Access Database Table with DataSet

Tags: c#, ms-access, .net-4.0, vba

I'm in the process of converting a vba program to c#.  The vba program modifies/adds rows to a recordset rst1 with values from a different recordset rst2.  The c# version uses OleDbDataAdapter to fill data from a query into dataset csrst1 table 0.

In the vba version, rst1.update seems to modify the database table rows directly.  The question is, is there a way to update the access database rows after updating/modifying the dataset?  Is there a better way to do this?

Here's what I've done so far...

```
vba:
rst1.FindFirst "[L1]=" & ![VendorID] & " AND [D1]=#" & ![REQ_IP_DATE] & "#"
If rst1.NoMatch Then
    rst1.AddNew
    '...new row fields set
    rst1.Update
Else
    rst1.Edit
    '...rows edited
    rst1.Update
End If
```

(The above code is within a With rst2 do loop.  The rst1 fields are updated with values from rst2.)

```
c#:
foreach(DataRow dr in csrst2.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var findfirst = csrst1.Tables[0].Select("[L1]=" + dr[0] + "  AND [D1]=#" + dr[1] + "#");
    if(findfirst.Count() < 1)
    {
        var newRow = csrst1.Tables[0].NewRow();
        //...new row fields set
        csrst1.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
    else
    {   
        findfirst[0].BeginEdit();
        //...rows edited
        findfirst[0].AcceptChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x.aspx, using adapter.update.  This seems to be really slow (takes 15-20 seconds to execute for 141 rows), so if there are any other solutions I'd like to hear about it!

Here's what I did:

```
c#:
OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
foreach(DataRow dr in csrst2.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var findfirst = csrst1.Tables[0].Select("[L1]=" + dr[0] + "  AND [D1]=#" + dr[1] + "#");
    if(findfirst.Count() < 1)
    {
        var newRow = csrst1.Tables[0].NewRow();
        //...new row fields set
        csrst1.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);
        adapter.Update(csrst1.Tables[0]);
    }
    else
    {   
        findfirst[0].BeginEdit();
        //...rows edited
        findfirst[0].AcceptChanges();
        adapter.Update(csrst1.Tables[0]);
    }
}
```